# Верна ли постановка знаков препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, оформление-текста, точка-с-запятой

Моя работа состоит в расшифровке аудиозаписи и, соответственно, в «натягивании» формальных правил пунктуации на звучащую речь. Закономерно возникают сомнения насчет правильности оформления предложений вроде:

> Библиотекари подбирали все эти книги и отдавали ему; он — хотя это не
> разрешалось — книги из зала выносить, — он эту связку приносил мне
> туда.

На ваш суд.

Answer (score 2):

Запись этой речи соответствует правилам.

Но на мой взгляд, предложение перегружено тире. Без среднего не обойтись, а вот крайние, выделяющие вставку, можно заменить скобками. Ну и вместо точки с запятой я бы поставил точку.

*"Библиотекари подбирали все эти книги и отдавали ему. Он (хотя это не разрешалось — книги из зала выносить), он эту связку приносил мне туда".*

Comment: Спасибо. Не подскажете, на каком основании ставится тире в `хотя это не разрешалось — книги из зала выносить`?

Comment: @d.biryukovv Спасибо за вопрос. Вторую часть можно рассматривать как уточнение  (*что именно не разрешалось, что **это***), а тире интонационным.